# Post an adaptive card as "User", from a Microsoft Form

Tags: power-automate, adaptive-cards

I've build a tool to improve the communication across my organization.

All the employees can fill-in a specific **Microsoft Form**, that will trigger automatically the publication of an adaptive card to a specific **Microsoft Teams channel.**.

Everything is working fine, except that these adaptive cards are published under my name, and not under the name of the user who filled the form in.

---

Any idea how I could fix that?
Many thanks !

The adaptive card properties are correctly set up **"Post As: User"**.
I've tried to use "Custom value" and inject the name of the user who filled-in the Microsoft from, with no succes